# How to validate an user answer button click javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I'm trying to create a quiz, right now it displays the first question with 4 answer choices after the start button I am stuck on how to retrieve the answer. The user clicks, check to see if its correct and loop to the next question. I just want to give the user one chance per question and move on regardless if it's correct or not. If their answer is wrong I will remove seconds from the timer. I have the questions, answer choices, and correct answers in arrays.

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <p id="header">
        You have 75 seconds to complete this asessment. 
        Every incorrect answer will cost you time.
        <br>
    </p>
    <button id="start-button" class="btn">Start</button>
    <div id="start-game" style="visibility: hidden">
        <button id="option0" data-index="0"></button><br>
        <button id="option1" data-index="1"></button><br>
        <button id="option2" data-index="2"></button><br>
        <button id="option3" data-index="3"></button><br>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

```js
var timerEl = document.getElementById("timer");
var start = document.getElementById("start-button");
var questionEl = document.getElementById("header");
var option0 = document.getElementById("option0");
var option1 = document.getElementById("option1");
var option2 = document.getElementById("option2");
var option3 = document.getElementById("option3");
var intials = document.getElementById("user-initials");
var buttonEl = document.getElementById("start-game");
var totalTime = 75;
var elapsedTime = 0;
var questionNum = 0;
var questions =["The condition in an if/else statement is enclosed with in _______",
                "Arrays in JavaScript can be used to store ______",
                "Commonly used data types do not include ______",
                "String values must be enclosed within _____ when being assigned to variables"];

var answers =[question1= ["Quotes","Curly brackets","Parentheses","Square brackets"],
              question2= ["Numbers and strings","Other arrays","Booleans","All of the above"],
              question3= ["Strings","Booleans","Alerts","Numbers"],
              question4= ["Commas","Curly brackets","quotes","parentheses"],
            ];             

var correctAnswers = [2,3,2,2];

start.addEventListener("click", function(){
    timer();
    displayQuestion();
    start.style.visibility = "hidden";
    buttonEl.style.visibility = "visible";
});



function timer(){

    var timerInterval = setInterval(function(){
        totalTime --;
        timerEl.textContent = totalTime;

        if(totalTime === 0){
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
        endQuiz();
        return;

    }
    }, 1000);
}

function newQuiz(){
    questionEl.textContent = (questions[0]);

};



function displayQuestion(){
for( var i = 0; i < questions.length ; i++){

    questionEl.textContent=(questions[i]);
    option0.textContent=(answers[i][0]);
    option1.textContent=(answers[i][1]);
    option2.textContent=(answers[i][2]);
    option3.textContent=(answers[i][3]);

    console.log(i);
    return;

}
}
```

Comment: You need to add handlers to your option buttons that when clicked check them selves against the current correct answer for that question and act accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Hi I will try to provide an easy solution to your question without using any kind of difficult javascript syntax so here goes..

First in your html file update the option button and add a class property called clickOption(you can change the class name if you want, but be sure to change in other places in script.js as well). The code is shown below.

```
<button id="option0" class="clickOption"  data-index="0"></button><br>
<button id="option1" class="clickOption"  data-index="1"></button><br>
<button id="option2" class="clickOption"  data-index="2"></button><br>
<button id="option3" class="clickOption"  data-index="3"></button><br>
```

Now in your script.js file add the line of code shown below. I have added inline comments for better understanding

```
// get all elements with class clickoption i.e all option buttons
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("clickOption");
//use the below array to track the selected answers
var selectedAnswers = [];


var clickOption = function() {
  /** Here I have reached the end of the test and,
      I am logging the array of user-selected options. 
      This array can be compared with correctAnswers array
      to determine whether the answer is correct or not  **/
 if(questionNum >= questions.length) {
    console.log(selectedAnswers);
    return;
 }
 /**Get the option value that was clicked.
    Here I am using parseInt because,
    the data-index attribute value will be in string format,
    and the correctAnswers array is in Number format so it is better,
    to keep the selectedAnswers array in Number format as it will faciliate
    easier data comparison**/  
 var selectedOption = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-index'));
 // add the selected option to the selectedAnwsers Array
 selectedAnswers.push(selectedOption);
 /** here I am assuming that you are using the questionNum variable 
     to track the current question Number **/
 questionNum += 1;
  /** here I am again checking if I have reached the end of test and 
      thus log the answers
      Instead of logging the answer you can create a function 
      that compares the result and display it on screen **/
 if(questionNum >= questions.length) {
    console.log(selectedAnswers);
    return;
 }
 // update the next question text
 questionEl.textContent = questions[questionNum];
 // update next options
 displayQuestion(questionNum);
}

//loop through all the elements with class clickOption 
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   elements[i].addEventListener('click', clickOption);
}

start.addEventListener("click", function() {
  timer();
  /** I have updated the displayQuestion call implementation
      so that the function is called with a parameter
      (here the parameter it is zero) **/
  displayQuestion(questionNum);
  start.style.visibility = "hidden";
  buttonEl.style.visibility = "visible";
});

/**Finally I have updated the display question method 
   so that it updates the option buttons based on the index parameter **/

 function displayQuestion(index){
  questionEl.textContent = questions[index];
  option0.textContent = answers[index][0];
  option1.textContent = answers[index][1];
  option2.textContent = answers[index][2];
  option3.textContent = answers[index][3];
 }
```

Hope this solution helps you. Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you so much this was very helpful. Would I still be using the selected answers array if I want to check if the answers are correct after each question and not at the end? I want to check after each one so i can take off timer from the timer if they are wrong and if they run out of time the quiz also ends. The timer is essentially reflecting their score.

Comment: For checking answers after each question you can add a conditional statement like the following. Add the line above the selectedAnswers.push statement.

`if(correctAnswers[questionsNum]===selectedOption) {   /.add your timer updation logic./     }` 

Hope this helps. 
Also if you liked the answer please upvote.